# Unity render Texture is not as clear as the actual gameobject in the scene, how to make it clearer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, textures

I tried changing the camera settings and the render texture, but nothing seems to work.

Camera:

[image]

Render Texture:

[image]

Output
[image]

[image]

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your screenshot resolution exceeds 1000x700, but your render texture is only 256x256.

Comment: yes, but the screenshot was taken manually so that is why. I also got to know from another user that if increase the size of the RT then I can have better quality. It seems similar to your concept so if you want to answer, I can make it as accepted.